# Finding a reason why table join fails

Tags: arcgis-pro, attribute-joins

I try to follow the 'visualize temporal data' tutorial step by step, but the table result doesn't match.[image: data detail]

The chinesetourism_transposed data store a float type yearly data from 1997-2017, and the territorial authorities data store many data that won't use. Both of them have the same territory vairable. I use the table join function by 2 territory variables.

The result should show each territorial authorities with the yearly data from 1997-2017.
Only territorial authorities that start with the letter 'W' is normal in my result, and the other authorities are all 'null' including the join table field.

I can't find out what happen now.

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

If I'm interpreting your screenshots correctly, your two join fields appear to be of type string (text).  If so, it is possible that one or both of those fields contain records with extra blank spaces that do not exist in the other table.  These can arise during keyboard data entry, and are difficult for the eye to spot.

This problem can be solved by editing the join fields in both tables to make them identical: search for leading and trailing blanks, as well as double blanks, and delete them. Then retry the join.

Welcome to SEGIS.

Comment: Hello smith,
I tried to copy paste some territories to the new table, but the result hasn't changed. I don't think it is the reason because those fields starting with 'W' are normal, like 'Wanganui' and the others are null.
like 'Wxxxxx' ...... 'Wxxxxx' 0.123123 1/1/1997                                
                           'Wxxxxx' 0.123132 1/1/1998        
       'Rxxxxx' ...... null nulll null                             
       'Waaaa' ...... 'Waaaa' 0.123123 1/1/1997

Comment: Hello aowu, I did not propose that you copy and paste.  Instead, I suggested that you *search* for blank spaces and then *delete* them.

Answer (score 0):

This is many to one join. It doesn't work, because only first record from joined table will appear in result. For example joining table at the bottom to one at the top:

[image]

Results in:

[image]

So do Pivot table first:
[image]

and join output to your polygons:

[image]